# authorize my rails 3 applicationd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, authorization, inherited-resources

I'm developing a rails 3 application using inherited_resources and devise.

I tried to use cancan as my authorization plugin and it wasn't enough (i need more complex conditions for my authorization rules).

I also tried using declarative_authorization but my rules didn't work for the "index" method of my controllers.

Is there a RELIABLE rails plugin to handle authorization ?!

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a list of authorization gems in [here](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization.html). My advice to you is you should give cancan a second chance. It handles almost everything about authorization.